# Exim4 as a relay only on our local network

Tags: debian, exim

I want to use alert email from CMC http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1987.dell-chassis-management-controller.

It's seems my Debian rejected its connection. Maybe Exim4 is misconfifured.

Below my configuration (/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf ) :

> dc_eximconfigçconfigtype='smarthost'
>   dc_other_hostnames=''
>   dc_local_interfaces=''
>   dc_readhost='serv-ftp'
>   dc_relay_domains=''
>   dc_minimaldns='false'
>   dc_relay_nets='' dc_smarthost='smtp GMAIL'
>   CFILMODE='644'
>   dc_use_split_config='false'
>   dc_hide_mailname='true'
>   dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
>   dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'

How i can open EXIM4 to be an open relay on my local network ?i want my cmc to be able to send mail through my serv-ftp.

At the moment, with this configuration only serv-ftp is able to send mail (tested from PHP, and mail command from ssh)

From /var/log/exim4/mainlog

> SMTP protocol synchronization error (input sent without waiting for greeting) : rejected connection from H = localhost [127.0.0.1] input"n\r"

Comment: This is not an exim configuration. This is the exim-related debian configuration.

Comment: You don't show the relevant lines from `/var/log/exim4/mainlog` when the rejection occurs. Please edit your question to include those. In any case, if you want to relay emails via this exim, you need to put the network from which the message originates in `dc_relay_nets`.

Comment: Hum ! That's was solved by adding '*' to dc_relay_domains and adduser alert with restricted permission. Now CMC can send mail with alert@192.168.0.13.